# Is there a way to report a rude/inappropriate username?

Tags: support, moderation, usernames

A new user just posted a question, and I find their username offensive and inappropriate (I can post the name if necessary). Is there any procedure for reporting a username?

I also found their question inappropriate, so I flagged it as such.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this name?

Comment: The question was also in poor taste. It has been deleted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should flag the post for moderator attention, and specify why you think the username is inappropriate.